# How to mesh an ASCII text file from pixel data - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to import data from a .txt file (ASCII text file) into Matlab to then mesh is to have a map of what is happening at each pixel (each pixel have a row and column # and corresponding value).

It is supposed to be a colormap of different air pressures are specific points of an image.

I cannot figure out how to make this happen. The txt file has 1200 rows and 1600 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a bit ambiguous. But here's how you read an ASCII file of a matrix and then plot the value of each cell as a colour.

```
rows = 1200;
cols = 1600;
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
A = fscanf(fid, '%f', [cols rows])'; % transpose so rows of matrix correspond to rows in text
fclose(fid)

imagesc(A)
shading interp
```